Not calculating gradients for backward propagation
I have following code for my custom loss function which I want to minimize but it doesnt calculate any gradients for the backwardpass.
My code for the custom loss function:
class CustomLossFunction(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, word2vec_model, glove_model, aesthetics_predictor, processor):
        super(CustomLossFunction, self).__init__()
        self.word2vec_model = word2vec_model
        self.glove_model = glove_model
        self.aesthetics_predictor = aesthetics_predictor
        self.processor = processor
        self.mse_loss = nn.MSELoss()

    def forward(self, predicted, target, images1, images2):
        # Berechne Metriken
        jaccard = self.jaccard_index(predicted, target)
        w2v_sim = self.word2vec_similarity(predicted, target)
        glove_sim = self.glove_similarity(predicted, target)
        ssim_score = self.compute_ssim(images1, images2)
        aesthetics_score = self.predict_aesthetics(images2)
        aesthetics_loss = 10.0 - aesthetics_score
        
        # Erstelle die Zielwerte in der gleichen Form wie die Metriken
        jaccard_target = torch.tensor(1.0, dtype=torch.float32, device=predicted.device)
        w2v_target = torch.tensor(1.0, dtype=torch.float32, device=predicted.device)
        glove_target = torch.tensor(1.0, dtype=torch.float32, device=predicted.device)
        ssim_target = torch.tensor(1.0, dtype=torch.float32, device=predicted.device)
        aesthetics_target = torch.tensor(0.0, dtype=torch.float32, device=predicted.device)
        
        # Wandle die Metriken in die Form um, die der Zielgröße entspricht
        jaccard = jaccard.unsqueeze(0)
        w2v_sim = w2v_sim.unsqueeze(0)
        glove_sim = glove_sim.unsqueeze(0)
        ssim_score = ssim_score.unsqueeze(0)
        aesthetics_loss = aesthetics_loss.unsqueeze(0)
        
        # Kombiniere Metriken mit MSE
        jaccard_loss = self.mse_loss(jaccard, jaccard_target.unsqueeze(0))  # Ziel ist 1.0
        w2v_loss = self.mse_loss(w2v_sim, w2v_target.unsqueeze(0))  # Ziel ist 1.0
        glove_loss = self.mse_loss(glove_sim, glove_target.unsqueeze(0))  # Ziel ist 1.0
        ssim_loss = self.mse_loss(ssim_score, ssim_target.unsqueeze(0))  # Ziel ist 1.0
        aesthetics_loss = self.mse_loss(aesthetics_loss, aesthetics_target.unsqueeze(0))  # 
        
        # Berechne den Gesamtverlust
        loss_value = (jaccard_loss + w2v_loss + glove_loss + ssim_loss + aesthetics_loss) / 5
        
        return loss_value

    def jaccard_index(self, text1, text2):
        set1 = set(preprocess_text(text1))
        set2 = set(preprocess_text(text2))
        intersection = len(set1 & set2)
        union = len(set1 | set2)
        return torch.tensor(intersection / union if union != 0 else 0.0, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)

    def word2vec_similarity(self, text1, text2):
        if self.word2vec_model is None:
            return torch.tensor(0.0, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
        
        words1 = preprocess_text(text1)
        words2 = preprocess_text(text2)
        vectors1 = [self.word2vec_model[word] for word in words1 if word in self.word2vec_model]
        vectors2 = [self.word2vec_model[word] for word in words2 if word in self.word2vec_model]
        if not vectors1 or not vectors2:
            return torch.tensor(0.0, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
        mean_vector1 = torch.tensor(np.mean(vectors1, axis=0), dtype=torch.float32, device=device, requires_grad=True)
        mean_vector2 = torch.tensor(np.mean(vectors2, axis=0), dtype=torch.float32, device=device, requires_grad=True)
        similarity = F.cosine_similarity(mean_vector1.unsqueeze(0), mean_vector2.unsqueeze(0))
        return similarity

    def glove_similarity(self, text1, text2):
        doc1 = self.glove_model(text1)
        doc2 = self.glove_model(text2)
        similarity = doc1.similarity(doc2)
        return torch.tensor(similarity, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)

    def compute_ssim(self, image1, image2):
        # Convert images to grayscale
        gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image1), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image2), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        
        # Compute SSIM between two images
        score, _ = ssim(gray1, gray2, full=True)
        return torch.tensor(score, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)

    def predict_aesthetics(self, image):
        # Verarbeite das Bild zu Tensoren
        inputs = self.processor(images=image, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
    
        # Vorhersage durchführen
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = self.aesthetics_predictor(**inputs)
    
        # Extrahiere den Wert aus den Ausgaben
        aesthetics_score = outputs.logits.item()
        return torch.tensor(aesthetics_score, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)

        
custom_loss_function = CustomLossFunction(
    word2vec_model=word2vec_model,
    glove_model=nlp,
    aesthetics_predictor=predictor,
    processor=processor
).to(devicetype here

Does anyone have an idea why its not calculating any gradients?
Implemented the MSE function to get a differentiable function but still doesn't calculate gradients.

Gradients cannot be propagated through OpenCV functions, you must only use pytorch functions inside the loss.
